# Counting from a specific range of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula without using VB to sum up a total number form a specific range of data?

For example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieFC6.jpg)

[image]

I need to sum up the number of times Mary took up the cooking lesson.

I understand that just by using the sum and manually select the range (B3:D3) I will be able to get it. But is there a formula to determine the range (B3:D3) instead?

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Determining range by formula is possible but what logic do you want to use? Like cooking hour greater than or less than or others logic?

Comment: Yes, you can use INDEX MATCH function to get expected output but condition is whether your excel format is fixed as you have shown in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the merged cells in row 1 necessitates building a range with a pair of [INDEX functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) which is then re-examined with another INDEX to pick the row of data with a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca). Once the range has been defined, a [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) produces the result.

[image: Index_in_Index]

The formula in C10 is,

```
=SUM(INDEX(INDEX($B$3:$J$6, 0, MATCH($B10, B$1:J$1, 0)):INDEX($B$3:$J$6, 0, MATCH($B10, B$1:J$1, 0)+2), MATCH($A10, $A$3:$A$6, 0), 0))
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: WOW!! it works great. Thanks. To improve it further, for the +2 to determine the size of the range, is there a way to write the formula to get it to determine by the merged cells?

For example, if the merged cells with the word "Cooking" is changed from merging of 3 columns to 4 columns, rather to change the "+2" to "+3" manually, is there a method to get the formula to update themselves??

Comment: I may have spoke too soon. I'll try and lookup some my of merged cell formulas to see what I've come up with in the past.